# Is it possible to set the fetch size for NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, odp.net

When retrieving rows from an oracle database using ODP.NET, I can specify the FetchSize parameter, which is the number of bytes that will be retrieved in one round-trip to the database.

Is it possible to set a FetchSize (or equivalent) for NHibernate? If so, how is this done?

If not, is there a default size that it retrieves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver` and override CreateCommand:

```
public override IDbCommand CreateCommand()
{
    var command = (OracleCommand)base.CreateCommand();
    command.FetchSize = desiredValue;
    return command;
}
```

Comment: do you know if it's possible to override the value per specific request? Some queries are expected to return 1 row of data, some 2000. It's not very efficient to set high fetch size globally.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, you can also set this in the registry or in the machine.config, web.config, or app.config:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/featConfig.htm